# HTTP redirect to HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

how can i redirect my site to https?
i already set on cpanel domain -> redirection
[image: Redirect Details from Cpanel Setting]

and here's my .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but when i type mydomain.com, its not redirect to www.mydomain.com
and because of it, i got bad certificates.
can someone know why i got this one for my website?

Answer (score 0):

In these lines :

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

You have enforced all  `http` requests into `https` as they are , whether come with or without `www`,

So , change these lines with this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^  https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test